# What does "the rates may be adjusted by the greater of 2%" mean in a contractual context?

Tags: meaning

The context is as follows:

> All rates set out in this contract may be adjusted by our company on each anniversary of the start date by the greater of 2%.

If I understand it correctly they mean that the rates may be increased or reduced by not more than 2%...but actually they've just increased it by 4%. Strange. Is the problem in my understanding or is the company trying to cheat?

Comment: I'd ask the company (after checking you've copied the text correctly). '... the greater of 2%' is ungrammatical.

Comment: Wheres the rest of the sentence?  “The greater of” is typically used when two options are possible: *The fee is the greater of $100 or 3%.*    In your case I’d guess it would be some index rate.  So if the LIBOR (for example) went up by 4% you’d see a 4% increase in your contract rate.  If the LIBOR was flat for the year, you’d still see a 2% rate increase.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it was written by someone who was not a native speaker of English. It is not clear at all. (I would ask for the contract in the original language and have it translated.)

I would guess that it means  "may be adjusted by our company on each anniversary of the start date by **more than** 2%." - This would account for the 4% hike.

Whether the company is trying to cheat is debatable but, if my interpretation is correct, the company could increase the rate by **any** percentage higher than 2% and that would be dangerous if you are paying the interest, but rewarding if you were receiving it.